# Share matplotlib interactive graph with others

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, interactive

Need help on understand the process of sharing matlplotlib interactive graphs. The graphs I am looking to share are geospatial plotting of map of India and corresponding data points.

I tried converting it to HTML but it gives a static page, also tried using nbinteract [here](https://avinashladdha.github.io/juvenile_crimes/article2.html) but it is throwing an error.
The code for the file whose output I want to share can be found [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/avinashladdha/juvenile_crimes/blob/master/article2.ipynb).

Also trying to understand if there are other ways to share interactive plot with others.

Comment: If you need shareable interactivity, you should look at libraries such as [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) and [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org). Specific for geographic data, there is [folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium).

Comment: @JohanC I tried working with bokeh but couldn't figure out how to plot geospatial data as per my need. Will check out plotly and folium. Thanks for the suggestions.